# Abstract away async calls to IMemoryCache in API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been using actions that look like Example 1 to async cache json results for my .NET Core API. `MemoryCache` is an instance of `IMemoryCache`.

**Example 1 (works as expected):**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction() =>
    Json(await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(
        "MyController_MyAction", 
        entry => myService.GetAllAsync()
    ));
```

The calls to `Json()` and `MemoryCache.GetOrCreate()` are duplicated in many of my actions. In my real app, there are even more duplicated implementation details such as setting the `AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow` value and returning `NotFound()` for nulls. I would like to abstract all of this away into a shared method so that each action passes only its unique details to the call of the shared method.

In order to do this, I extracted a variable for each of the two variables that are in my actions. e.g.:

**Example 2 (cache neither updated nor retrieved from):**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
{
    var task = myService.GetAllAsync();
    const string cacheKey = "MyController_MyAction";
    return Json(await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, entry => task));
}
```

The next step would be to extract a shared method `Get()` like:

**Example 3 (doesn't work because Example 2 doesn't work):**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
{
    var task = myService.GetAllAsync();
    const string cacheKey = "MyController_MyAction";
    return await Get(task, cacheKey);
}

protected async Task<IActionResult> Get(Task<T> task, string cacheKey =>
    return Json(await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, entry => task));
```

Example 1 successfully retrieves subsequent results from the cache. Example 2, however, finds `null` in the cache on subsequent requests and retrieves the data anew each time (as verified by temp debug `TryGetValue()` statements as well as monitoring the underlying SQL queries hitting my database).

To me, Example 1 and Example 2 should be identical. However, maybe my understanding of async/await and Tasks is lacking (very likely).

How can I abstract away the duplicated implementation details (such as `Json()` and `MemoryCache.GetOrCreate()` calls) from my actions while still successfully updating and retrieving from the `IMemoryCache` in an async manner?

Comment: Your task variable needs to be a function/lambda in ex 2 to get it equivalent to ex 1.

Comment: @MicroVirus Thanks, can you share an example of what that would look like (if its possible with my example)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var task = myService.GetAllAsync();
```

This will already run the `GetAllAsync` method, so by doing this, you are preventing the lazy behavior of the memory cache where it would only call the method when the cache key is not available.

In order to keep doing that, you will have to store an actual expression that creates the value, so you would have to do this:

```
Func<MyObject> createValue = () => myService.GetAllAsync();
const string cacheKey = "MyController_MyAction";
return Json(await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, entry => createValue()));
```

So, abstracting that away, this is what you could end up with:

```
public Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
    => GetCache("MyController_MyAction", () => myService.GetAllAsync());
```

The method would be implemented like this:

```
private async Task<IActionResult> GetCache<T>(string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> createAction)
{
    var result = await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, entry => createAction());
    return Json(result);
}
```

If the cache key is always `<ControllerName>_<ActionName>`, you could even go one more step and automatically infer that from the call using the [`CallerMemberNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute):

```
private async Task<IActionResult> GetCache<T>(Func<Task<T>> createAction, [CallerMemberName] string actionName = null)
{
    var cacheKey = GetType().Name + "_" + actionName;
    var result = await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, entry => createAction());
    return Json(result);
}
```

So you can just use it like this:

```
public Task<IActionResult> MyAction()
    => GetCache(() => myService.GetAllAsync());
```

Comment: Nice. I do get "CS0411 The type arguments for method '`CacheExtensions.GetOrCreateAsync<TItem>(IMemoryCache, object, Func<ICacheEntry, Task<TItem>>)`' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." in your suggested `GetCache()` implementation. I tried `var result = await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync<T>(cacheKey, entry => createAction());`, but that throws a couple other exceptions. Any ideas?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include the `Task` in the `Func` type there. The method argument should be `Func<Task<T>> createAction`.

Answer (score 1):

`var task = myService.GetAllAsync();` isn't going to create the Func signature that you need.

> `public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TItem> GetOrCreateAsync<TItem> (
>       this Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.IMemoryCache cache, 
>       object key, 
>       Func<Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.ICacheEntry,
>            System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TItem>> factory
>   );`
>    - [CacheExtensions.GetOrCreateAsync <sup>MSDN</sup>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Instead, create the func

```
Func<ICacheEntry,Task<TItem>> taskFunc = entry => myService.GetAllAsync();
```

And then re-use it as needed

```
return Json(await MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(cacheKey, taskFunc));
```